# Multiple arguments involving multiple cells

Tags: google-sheets

I need help on a project that I have been working on.  I need cell4 to have 3 inputs based on cell1,2 and 3. If cell1 has value, cell4 will show ABC. IF cell1 & 2 has value, cell4 will show DEF and if cell1, 2 & 3 all has values, cell4 will show GHI.

Can someone help me with a code for this?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: can you share a link to your google sheets ?

Answer (score -1):

is this result correct for you?
[image]

that result could be obtained with:

```
=IFS(and(A2:A<>"",B2:B<>"",C2:C<>""),"GHI",and (A2:A<>"",B2:B<>""),"DEF",A2:A<>"","ABC",A2:A="","")
```

(calculation to be extended to the cells of the desired rows)

this formula uses comma as separator... you can change ALL commas with semi-colon if your system needs it

Comment: Hi, Thank you for answering my question. However what I need to have is Cell4 to be dynamic which changes the input once cells 1-3 has been filled up. So when I input a value for cell1, the cell4 would show ABC then once cell2 has value, cell4 would show DEF and once cells 1 to 3 has been filled with value, cell4 would show GHI. Thank you for helping me on this. Hope you have a wonderful day Daniele!

Comment: your comment does not clarify what you actually want to achieve, rather it complicates it.
Please attach a screenshot of what you want

Comment: My apologies. I'm new to this and during my time there was never a need for us to do this stuff. I think I can try out your formula on the initial photo that you have sent. Would you be so kind to share how did you do it?

Thanks so much for your patience.

Comment: @rei I updated my answer

Comment: Thank you so much this is great help for me and to my team.

Comment: @Rei Please checkout [What should I do when someone answers my questions?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)